# Calling WebMethod via jQuery from JavaScript on ASCX, needing value of Control

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I understand how to use jQuery to make an AJAX call to a WebMethod from a normal page, but I'm running into problems doing it from a UserControl (ASCX). Right now the biggest Issue I'm having is that the JavaScript for getting access to the groupDropDown control is not working.  It seems that since this is a UserControl hosted within DotNetNuke, the ususal method of getting the CLientID is not working since it is nested down x number of levels. Here is what I have:

Javascript:

```
function validateEnrolledDate(src, args) {
    var isValid;
    var groupDropDown = document.getElementById('<%= ddlDealer.ClientID %>');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajaxservice.asmx/ValidateEnrolledDate",
        data: "{orderDate: '" + args.Value + "', groupId: '" + groupId + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
            isValid = msg.d;
        },
        failure: function () {
            alert("FAIL");
        }
    });
    args.IsValid = isValid;
```

Validator User Control that calls this JavaScript:

```
<asp:CustomValidator id="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="rdiDate" ErrorMessage="Fail" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate" ValidationGroup="vgce" CssClass="validation" Display="Dynamic" Text="*" ClientValidationFunction="validateEnrolledDate" />
```

groupDropDown I'm trying to get a value from:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDealer" runat="server" CssClass="dropdownlist theDealer" TabIndex="3" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDealers_Changed" />
```

WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod()]
    private bool ValidateEnrolledDate(string orderDate, string groupId)
    {
        DateTime enrolledDate = new Service().GetEnrollmentDate(int.Parse(groupId));

        if (DateTime.Parse(orderDate) >= enrolledDate)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**TIME TO SIMPLIFY:**
Here is testing JS Code:

```
function validateEnrolledDate(src, args) {
    var isValid;
    var selectedGroup = $("theDealer").val();

    alert(selectedGroup);
}
```

I'm now just referencing a TextBox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="dealerId" runat="server" CssClass="theDealer" />
```

The Text in the Textbox is being set in Server Side code, and it is visible on screen.

The alert message is "undefined", so something is still happening so that it is not getting the value of that textbox...

Comment: I realize that I did not really say that, so I edited the question to expand a bit more.  Basically var groupDropDown = document.getElementById('<%= ddlDealer.ClientID %>'); is failing to work right now.  No error message, but FireFox says: Content Encoding Error.  If I remove the line with .ClientID it starts working, but the JavaScript function fails.

Comment: I see you are trying to get a value from `document.getElementById('<%= ddlDealer.ClientID %>');` but you reference `ddlUsers` as the ddl you want to get, should that be `ddlDealer` instead?

Comment: sorry, Dealer is what I want to get.  I'l edit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are having trouble getting the value of the drop down list the easist approach would be to assign a class to the control.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlUsers" runat="server" CssClass="dropdownlist theUsers" TabIndex="5" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlUsers_SelectedIndexChanged" Enabled="false" />
```

and than in your method.

```
var selectedUser = $("theUsers option:selected").val();
```

Comment: This feels right, as soon as I get it working I'll let you know :)